# Dynamically allocating space for an array and trying to constrain the values

Tags: arrays, c

My code dynamically allocates memory. I am trying to store the elements keeping a constraint for the values stored but it doesn't work when I keep the constraint.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, sum = 0;
    int *arr;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n >= 1000 || n <= 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    arr = (int *)malloc(n * (sizeof(int)));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] >= 1000)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    printf("%d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

I think the mistake is here

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] >= 1000)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if (arr[i] >= 1000)
{
    return 0;
}
scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
```

The `if` statement checks the value of `arr[i]` before `scanf` actually reads the value in. `scanf` needs to run before the `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You're evaluating indeterminate content (which invokes undefined behavior), and in reality never actually evaluating the values-just-read. In short, this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] >= 1000)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

should be this instead (including IO error checking):

```
for (i = 0; i < n && scanf("%d", arr+i) == 1; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] >= 1000)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    sum += arr[i];
}
```

That said, I see no need for any array here in the first place, dynamic or otherwise. Accumulating a sum can be done with two `int` values: the value just-read, and the accumulator to which it is added: E.g. The dynamic memory management is pointless:

```
int value;
for (i = 0; i < n && scanf("%d", &value) == 1; i++)
{
    if (value >= 1000)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    sum += value;
}
```

Doing the above and completely throwing out all code that has anything to do with `arr` will accomplish your apparent goal.

Answer (score 0):

Take input before checking that value in arr[i] is >= 1000. Because when malloc allocates n memory it is initialized by garbage value. And here you are checking before inputting in this situation if garbage value is greater than or equal to 1000 , your program will stop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i, sum = 0;
    int *arr;
    printf("Enter number :");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (n >= 1000 || n <= 1)
        return 0;

    arr = (int *)malloc(n * (sizeof(int)));
    if(arr == NULL){
        printf("memory not allocated ");
        exit(0);
    }    
    printf("\nenter %d numbers : ",n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        if (arr[i] >= 1000)
            return 0;
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    printf("\nSUM = %d", sum);
    return 0;
}
```